# Как изменить название окна в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

[image: Класс Nameprogram]

Функция `Nameprogram` перестала функционировать, не получается изменить название окна и её иконку.

**main.py**

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
    from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    ################################## Тут вызовы  ui файлов

    from Apex import Ui_MainWindow
    from weaponsUI import Ui_other
    from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1

    ###############################
    class ApexHelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
            super(ApexHelper, self).__init__() 
            self.Apex = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.Apex.setupUi(self)
            self.NameProgramm()
            
            self.Apex.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon)# Кнопка чтобы переходить на другое окно
            ################ Теперь плавное изменение окна
            
    def NameProgramm(self):
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('gg.jpg'))
    

    def gotoWeapon(self):
            application1=Weapon()
            widget.addWidget(application1) # даёт возможность перейти на 2 слайд
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
            
    #### Начало класса описания оружия
    class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
            super(Weapon, self).__init__()
            self.weaponsUI = Ui_other()
            self.weaponsUI.setupUi(self)
            self.weaponsUI.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
            self.weaponsUI.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi)

    def gotomain(self):
            #application = ApexHelper()
            widget.addWidget(application) #ДОБАВИЛ ВИДЖЕТ ТУТ И НИЖЕ - даёт возможность перейти на 1 слайд
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

    def gotowedomi(self): #направить на класс описания пушки wedomi
            application2 = wedomi() # экземпляр класса ведомый 
            widget.addWidget(application2)
            widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)


    #####Начало класса описание Wedomiy

    class wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
            super(wedomi, self).__init__()
            self.wedomiy = Ui_MainWindow1()
            self.wedomiy.setupUi(self)
            

    #create app   
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApexHelper() #apexhelper - начальный класс мать всего
    #application.resize(550, 246)
    application.show() # работает без него




    ##########################################################################

    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget() #добавление виджетов
    widget.addWidget(application) #добавить индекс в экземпляр application класса ApexHelper !!!!!!И ТУТ ДОБАВИЛ!!! Тут изначально показывает программу её мэин
    #widget.addWidget(application1) #добавить индекс в экземпляр application1 класса screen2


    widget.show() #показывает все виджеты 


    #main loop
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Apex.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(230, 651)
            MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
            self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
            self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
            self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Arial Black")
            font.setPointSize(24)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.label_2.setFont(font)
            self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000;\n"
    "border: 2px solid #B8860B;\n"
    "border-radius: 30;\n"
    "color: white")
            self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_2)
            self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setText("")
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("gg.jpg"))
            self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label)
            self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
            sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
            self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
            self.weapon.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Arial Black")
            font.setPointSize(12)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.weapon.setFont(font)
            self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.weapon)
            self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_14)
            self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_13)
            self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_12)
            self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_10)
            self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_11)
            self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
            self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
            self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
            self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
            self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
            self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
            self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
            self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 230, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ApexHelper"))
            self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapon"))
            self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
            self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**weaponsUI.py**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


    class Ui_other(object):
    def setupUi(self, other):
            other.setObjectName("other")
            other.resize(610, 683)
            other.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
            other.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(other)
            self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
            self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setText("")
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("hqdefault.jpg"))
            self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.wedom = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.wedom.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.wedom.setObjectName("wedom")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.wedom)
            self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
            self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
            self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
            self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
            self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
            self.back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.back.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
    "color: white;\n"
    "background-color: #800000;\n"
    "}")
            self.back.setObjectName("back")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.back)
            self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 10, 1, 1, 1)
            self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
            self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
            self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            font = QtGui.QFont()
            font.setFamily("Arial Black")
            font.setPointSize(24)
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setWeight(75)
            self.label_2.setFont(font)
            self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000;\n"
    "border: 2px solid #B8860B;\n"
    "border-radius: 30;\n"
    "color: white")
            self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
            self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 1, 2, 1)
            other.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(other)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 610, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            other.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(other)
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            other.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(other)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(other)

    def retranslateUi(self, other):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            other.setWindowTitle(_translate("other", "MainWindow"))
            self.wedom.setText(_translate("other", "Ведомый(Wigman)"))
            self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("other", "Re-45 Auto"))
            self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("other", "p2020"))
            self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("other", "Ищейка (Prowler Burst PDW)"))
            self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("other", "Сменщик (Alternator SMG)"))
            self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("other", "R-99"))
            self.back.setText(_translate("other", "Назад"))
            self.label_2.setText(_translate("other", "Оружие"))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    other = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_other()
    ui.setupUi(other)
    other.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

wedomiy.py

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 


    class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(494, 691)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
            self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
            self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.label.setText("")
            self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("wedomiy.png"))
            self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
            self.opisanieWed = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
            self.opisanieWed.setStyleSheet("background-color: #708090;\n"
    "color: black")
            self.opisanieWed.setText('')
            self.opisanieWed.setObjectName("opisanieWed")
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.opisanieWed)
            self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
            self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
            self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 494, 21))
            self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
            MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
            self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
            self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
            self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
            MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
            

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow1()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот исходный код и почему-то в названии окна написано Python, хотя должно быть написано `ApexHelper`, на всех окнах

[image: error]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Всё добавил, можете посмотреть

Comment: я попробую посмотреть ваше приложение, но после того как вы опубликуете модули `weaponsUI.py`, `wedomiy.py`.

Comment: Всё,сделано, смотрите

Comment: Я заметил, что если в конце закомментировать эти три строчки, то название Python пропадает  (widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(application)
widget.show()) Только вот, что дальше

Comment: я посмотрю ваше приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QStackedWidget` предоставляет стек виджетов,
в котором одновременно виден только один виджет. Более https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#details

- Создаем главное окно - `MainWindow`.
- Создаем центральный виджет - `self.centralWidget = QWidget()`.
- Создаем `self.stack = QStackedWidget()`,
  который размещаем с центральный виджет  `hbox.addWidget(self.stack)`.
- Все, дальше указываем индекс виджета, который будем показывать  - `self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)`.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import * 
from Apex import Ui_MainWindow


#from weaponsUI import Ui_other
class Ui_other(object):
    def setupUi(self, other):
        other.setObjectName("other")
        other.resize(610, 683)
        other.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        other.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(other)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        
#        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("hqdefault.jpg"))
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(200, 200))               # !?  scaled 
        
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
#-?        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        self.wedom = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.wedom.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.wedom.setObjectName("wedom")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.wedom)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.back = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.back.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.back.setObjectName("back")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.back)
#        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 10, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        
#        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()                    # + QVBoxLayout
        
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000;\n"
"border: 2px solid #B8860B;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)                                   # +++
        
#        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        
        other.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(other)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 610, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        other.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(other)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        other.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(other)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(other)

    def retranslateUi(self, other):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        other.setWindowTitle(_translate("other", "MainWindow"))
        self.wedom.setText(_translate("other", "Ведомый(Wigman)"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("other", "Re-45 Auto"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("other", "p2020"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("other", "Ищейка (Prowler Burst PDW)"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("other", "Сменщик (Alternator SMG)"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("other", "R-99"))
        self.back.setText(_translate("other", "Назад"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("other", "Оружие"))


#from wedomiy import Ui_MainWindow1
class Ui_MainWindow1(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(494, 691)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"))                                # wedomiy.png
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.opisanieWed = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.opisanieWed.setStyleSheet("background-color: #708090;\n"
"color: black")
        self.opisanieWed.setText('')
        self.opisanieWed.setObjectName("opisanieWed")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.opisanieWed)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 494, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        
#     W <---
class Wedomi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow1):                            # + Ui_MainWindow1
    def __init__(self):
        super(Wedomi, self).__init__()
#        self.wedomiy = Ui_MainWindow1()
        self.setupUi(self)                                                      # +


class Weapon(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_other):                                  # + Ui_other
    def __init__(self):
        super(Weapon, self).__init__()
#        self.weaponsUI = Ui_other()
        self.setupUi(self)                                                      # -
#-        self.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
#-        self.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi)

#    def gotomain(self):
#        #application = ApexHelper()
#        widget.addWidget(application) #ДОБАВИЛ ВИДЖЕТ ТУТ И НИЖЕ - даёт возможность перейти на 1 слайд
#        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)
#
#    def gotowedomi(self):                               # направить на класс описания пушки wedomi
#        application2 = wedomi()                         # экземпляр класса ведомый 
#        widget.addWidget(application2)
#        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)


class ApexHelper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          # + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ApexHelper, self).__init__(parent) 
#        self.Apex = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)                                                       # +


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)        
        
        self.apexHelper = ApexHelper(self)
        self.apexHelper.weapon.clicked.connect(self.gotoWeapon) 

        self.weapon = Weapon()
        self.weapon.back.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)
        self.weapon.wedom.clicked.connect(self.gotowedomi)   
        
        self.wedomi = Wedomi()
        self.btnMain = QtWidgets.QPushButton("GoTo Main")                                     # +++
        self.btnMain.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {color: white; background-color: #800000;}")  # +++
        self.btnMain.clicked.connect(self.gotomain)                                           # +++
        self.wedomi.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btnMain)                                    # +++
        
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()                                                         # !!!               
        self.stack.addWidget(self.apexHelper)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.weapon)        
        self.stack.addWidget(self.wedomi)
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())        

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stack)
       
    def nameProgramm(self, w=0):
        if w == 0:
            self.setWindowTitle('Apex Helper')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('lena.jpg'))                             # gg.jpg 
        elif w == 1:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Weapon')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('im.png'))                               # !!!    
        elif w == 2:   
            self.setWindowTitle('Wedomi')
            self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))                               # !!!                

    def gotomain(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        
    def gotoWeapon(self):  
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())
        
    def gotowedomi(self):
        self.stack.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.nameProgramm(self.stack.currentIndex())


if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()                                             # --- ApexHelper(), +++ MainWindow
    w.show()                               
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Apex.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(230, 651)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000;\n"
"border: 2px solid #B8860B;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        
#        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg"))                            # gg.jpg
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("lena.jpg").scaled(120, 120))            # !?  scaled                          
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label)
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.weapon.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.weapon)
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_14)
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_13)
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_12)
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_10)
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_11)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_8)
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_7)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"color: white;\n"
"background-color: #800000;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 230, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ApexHelper"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapon"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А строки кода которые вы закомментировали, их типо можно убрать?

Comment: Чуть вышек кинул скрин, какая-то странная ошибка, и подскажите вы всё делаете вручную (код) или как-то через Qt Designer

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер о какой ошибке вы говорите? Вы пробовали запустить мой пример? Мой пример для вас не работает?

Comment: Да, я скопировал ваш код и мне выдало ошибку, посмотрите выше, я скинул скриншот ошибки

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер скопируйте два файла, которые я вам предоставил в ответе. Из CMD/консоли/терминала запустите `python main.py` и если у вас появится ошибка, приведете ее в текстовом виде, а не картинке. Обратите внимание на строки: `def __init__(self, parent=None):` и `super(ApexHelper, self).__init__(parent)`

Comment: Я всё скопировал и у меня запустилось... Очень сложно понять, как вы всё это делаете и что у меня не правильно

Comment: Я вам ещё выше задал вопрос, вы пишите вручную или вы используете qtDesigner(я думаю так удобнее) и скажите где можно изучить общие принципы, нормальной информации я не смог найти

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер я пишу по-разному, чего и вам желаю. https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/firstprograms/